# Camel simple expression throws NPE

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

In Camel (JBoss Fuse, Spring DSL specifically) I am trying to read a boolean value with Camel Simple expression.

```
<simple resultType="java.lang.Boolean">${body} != null and ${body.fielda} != null and ${body.fielda.fieldb} != null and ${body.fielda.fieldb}</simple>

<simple resultType="java.lang.Boolean">${body?.fielda?.fieldb}</simple>
```

${body} is a valid non-null POJO, 'fielda' is another nested POJO and fieldb is a boolean value.
Fielda can be null, but body is not.

When fielda is non null, I am able to read the value without error.

From various documentation sources (Apache Camel Simple, JBoss Fuse) it is stated that

> ?.

construct can be used as null-safe fields reads.

Both of the above throws NPE when fielda is null and practically I am unable to provide a null safe read here.
Thanks for the help.

Stack is as follows:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.camel.component.bean.ConstantBeanHolder.<init>(ConstantBeanHolder.java:43)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$OgnlInvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:264)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:114)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:132)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.evaluate(ExpressionDefinition.java:120)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.evaluate(ExpressionDefinition.java:112)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$34.evaluate(ExpressionBuilder.java:843)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.builder.BinaryPredicateSupport.matchesReturningFailureMessage(BinaryPredicateSupport.java:60)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.builder.BinaryPredicateSupport.matches(BinaryPredicateSupport.java:50)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.BinaryExpression$5.evaluate(BinaryExpression.java:227)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.util.ExpressionToPredicateAdapter.matches(ExpressionToPredicateAdapter.java:37)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.matches(SimpleBuilder.java:76)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:90)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip$2.doInAsyncProducer(RoutingSlip.java:301)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:304)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip.processExchange(RoutingSlip.java:294)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip.doRoutingSlip(RoutingSlip.java:215)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip.process(RoutingSlip.java:146)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:113)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:84)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[111:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.service(CamelContinuationServlet.java:162)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-jetty-common:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)[66:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0.0]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:136)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelFilterWrapper.doFilter(CamelFilterWrapper.java:43)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-jetty-common:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[70:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: Use the Red Hat customer portal to get help with the JBoss Fuse product

Answer (score 0):

```
       <setProperty propertyName="propName">
           <xpath resultType="java.lang.Boolean">//*[local-name()='NodeName'][text() = 'true']</xpath>
       </setProperty>
```

This works absolutely reliable and in a null-safe manner. I am more than disappointed, Camel.

Comment: Does this works when body is POJO? I thought that this only for xml/xslt

Comment: Yes, it works. I placed this to a context where my body is still a String (before POJO conversion).

Answer (score 0):

The ?. syntax you're attempting to use only works with Spring Expression Language (SPEL).  Please review the Camel docs here: http://camel.apache.org/spel.html

Here's an example from that page:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:foo"/>
  <filter>
    <spel>#{request.headers['foo'] == 'bar'}</spel>
    <to uri="direct:bar"/>
  </filter>
</route>
```

Comment: I cannot find anything about ?. on the linked SPEL page, but I am able to find it on http://camel.apache.org/simple.html. Are you sure?

Comment: Fairly sure, yes...  That syntax is SPEL, not Camel's Simple language.  Not sure why it's on the Simple page...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getter methods for those fields if you have them available:

```
${body.getFielda} != null and ${body.fetFielda.getFieldb} != null
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried switching the statements? For example:

```
<simple>null != {${body}</simple>
```

Comment: Nice idea but it seems like Camel Simple does not support this construct: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unexpected token null

Comment: Why are you downvoting that suggestion? You do realise I can edit the answer and suggestion a better one. Never mind.

Comment: Because it does not solve the problem but even more, throws an exception because its illegal in Camel. Edit: okay, I will re-check but I cannot remove downvote.